# Exposing React Component Functions

Tags: reactjs, components

What's the correct option to expose some react component functions based on best practices.

## OPTION 1

Create the function externally of the component like:

```
export const someFunction = () => { //do something }

class MyComponent extends Component {}

export default MyComponent;
```

Using the component above:

```
import MyComponent, { someFunction } from './components/myAwesomeComponent';  

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    parentComponentFunction() {
       someFunction();
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            <MyComponent />
        </div>
    }
}
```

## OPTION 2

Create the function internally (common way) of the component like:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    someFunction() {
     // 
    }
 }

export default MyComponent;
```

Using the component above:

```
import MyComponent frrom './components/myAwesomeComponent';  

class ChildComponent extends Component {

    parentComponentFunction() {
          this.refs.parentComponent.someFunction();
    }

    render() {
       <div>
         <MyComponent ref="parentComponent" />
       </div>
    }

}
```

## Option 3

Have no idea if it exists

Does it make sense or do you need a better example?

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Please state clearly what you are trying to achieve. In general you never want to "call" component methods. Instead, pass the function from one component to another using props.

Comment: It is a music player and the someFunction() is something like play, stop and so on... I wanna to create a component with that player, and instead of the component contains it's own buttons I want to expose the functions.

I know the way of my passing as props functions, but it works only from parent to child... what I want is inverse, but I don't know if it is a good practice. 

Thanks

Comment: React requires you to work in a more declarative way. Instead of `MusicComponent.play()` you would have `<MusicComponent play={true} />` or `<MusicComponent status="playing" />`. Parents pass props to their children and only props. But those props can change, and it's by changing the props that parents manipulate their children.

Comment: Gotcha. But the problem here is because Triton doesn’t have a component and I have to import its CDN, and the idea is the user just add my component and everything works fine, but with the freedom to have his/her own controls like play, stop 'n so on.
What I can do to avoid that concept is, the user must pass the player (triton var) into my component, and I can use it there and the user still has the option to use my controls or, his own controls.

Comment: I’m not 100% comfortable with my component, however, it is not too bad, because of this I decided to get some experts opinion.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Hey David.. thanks for your time, I did a better solution at least for me lol.

I used HoC and it worked like a charm.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `someFunction` needs to reference `this`, then define it as a member function. Otherwise either keep it as a separate utility function or declare it as static function inside the class (option 3):

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    // ...

    static someFunction() {
      // ...
    }
}

// usage: MyComponent.someFunction()
```

Also there is a ESLint rule, that should control it: [class-methods-use-this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this)

Comment: It worked for me (option 3).

And also I exported my static functions as:
export const someFunction = MyComponent.someFuntion;

So I could use something like: 
import MyComponent, { someFunction } from './components/myAwesomeComponent';

Thank you for your answer.